# Docker Network moving from the default bridge

Tags: docker, networking

I have a bunch of docker containers running on the default bridge network, that need to communicate with each other.

I want to move some of the containers to a separate user defined network so I can specify their IP addresses.

Is there any way to do this without having to take down/replicate all the containers and move them to the other network, or is this the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create networks and connect containers while they are live. You may still need to stop/start processes if the process is listening on specific a IP addresses rather than all interfaces (`*` or `::` )

#### Create a network

```
docker network create \
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=192.168.38.0/24 \
  --gateway=172.16.238.1 \
  <NETWORK>
```

#### Connect a container

```
docker network connect \
  --ip 192.168.38.14 \
  <NETWORK> \
  <CONTAINER>
```

#### Disconnect from original network

```
 docker network disconnect <OLDNETWORK> <CONTAINER>
```

#### Example

Before the containers `eth0` is on the default bridge network

```
→ docker exec $CONTAINER ip ad sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: eth0@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.4/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Afterwards, `eth1` has been added and no more `eth0`

```
→ docker exec $CONTAINER ip ad sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: eth1@if18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:26:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.38.14/24 brd 192.168.38.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: This is a great answer and exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to change whatever originally create the containers too!

Answer (score 0):

You also should think about using a docker compose. It will create a network automatically, with its own DNS, allowing the containers to be connected.